# How to play two side by side videos from youtube api

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to make side by side player and want to fetch videos from YouTube, but I am unable to do it because it demands `onInitializaionLisetener` and inside it we can play only one video by using `play.cueVideo("VideoId")`.

Please help me if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Android YouTube API doesn't allow to do that, because of performance.
You can try to play video using WebView and `<iframe>` tag, but it`s not a good idea.

The best way of doing that is to implement list view with thumbnails, and onItemClick show dialog or some frame, and play video there.

Here is a [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) from Youtube API doc.

And if you decide to use WebView for this, do not use default WebView, take a look at [Advanced Webview](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2390) or [FinestWebView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2861).

Comment: Thanks for heling me. R you suggesting that videowall kind of thing ?

Comment: Exactly. Also you can check ListView videos, it's a bit simpler. I think it calls VideoListDemoActivity.java in YouTube samples directory.